# How to implement navigation dots in this simple jquery image slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot figure out what would be the most efficient way of implementing navigation dots in a carousel structured in this way, any suggestion?

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Slider test</title>
    <script src="JQuery-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js-slider.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css-slider-test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TEST FOR BASIC IMAGE SLIDER</h1>
    <div id="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li class="slide"><img id="image1" data-target="#dot1" src="immagine1-slider.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slide"><img id="image2" data-target="#dot2" src="immagine2-slider.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slide"><img id="image3" data-target="#dot3" src="immagine3-slider.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slide"><img id="image4" data-target="#dot4" src="immagine4-slider.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slide"><img id="image5" data-target="#dot5" src="immagine5-slider.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slide"><img id="2nd-image1" data-target="#dot1" src="immagine1-slider.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-dots">
        <div id="dot1" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot2" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot3" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot4" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot5" class="dot"></div>
    </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Configuration
var width = 720;
var animationSpeed = 1000;
var pause = 3000;
var currentSlide = 1;

//Cache DOM
var $slider = $('#slider');
var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');


//interval needs to be initially set to undefined since it must be a global variable
//for reusability purposes
var interval;


//starting function
function startSlider(){
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
            currentSlide++;
            if(currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                currentSlide = 1;
                $slideContainer.css('margin-left',0);
            }
        });
    }, pause);
};

//pause function
function stopSlider() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

//listen for mouseenter and pause
//resume on mouseleave
$slider.on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);

//start slider when page is loaded
startSlider();

});
```

And finally this is my css:

```
img{
    width: 720px;
    height: 400px;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#slider{
    width:720px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:block;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
#slider .slides{
    display: block;
    width: 6000px;
    height: 400px;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
    #slider .slide{
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 720px;
    height: 400px;
}
.nav-dots{
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.dot{
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #151515;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't know why you're trying to create a slider from scratch when there are so many good sliders out there with way more features than the one you're making. It also says you have an error in your syntax. http://jsfiddle.net/szjhtjzh/

Comment: it's because I'm new to web development and although I know there are much better options, I figured knowing what are the basic principles of an image slider could be a good thing :)

Comment: Alright then, fix your syntax first ^_^

Comment: sorry didn't save the changes one more minute

Comment: I still see: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`. Look in your developers console (F12)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aletaie/1kcn50pn/ this hopefully should link to the right one sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I think it might be a better idea to create a function called `moveSilde()` then you can hook the <kbd>dots</kbd> that when clicked that function will fire and the slides will move. Also, give `.dot` class the property: `cursor: pointer;`